# Counters for use in array/tabular cells

Tags: tables, conditionals, counters, arrays

The following practical example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcounter{tabcol}\newcounter{tabrow}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\stepcounter{tabcol}}c}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{>{\stepcounter{tabrow}\setcounter{tabcol}{1}}CCC}
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol)
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}​
```

outputs row and column indices:

[image]

Somewhat inspired by the construction of [Auto generate table with tons of + and -](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65610/5764), what would be the most flexible way to implement a row/column indexing system like above that would fit within the standard `tabular` and `array` environments *without* having to intervene with the column specification?

For example, mixing `l`, `c` and `r` (and `X` and other) column types requires one to define a new column type to step the appropriate column for *every* such column type, which isn't very convenient.

As mentioned, I am interested in a technique of incorporating these counters with the traditional `tabular` and `array` environments (and therefore not something like a `tikz` matrix).

The end-game would be to use the row/column indices to condition on the cell contents (perhaps colouring, perhaps some output or whatever); similar in style to the following elementary example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcounter{tabcol}\newcounter{tabrow}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\stepcounter{tabcol}}c}
\newcommand{\oddornot}{\relax\ifodd\numexpr\value{tabrow}+\value{tabcol}\relax odd\else even\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{tabrow}\setcounter{tabcol}{1}}CCC}
  \oddornot & \oddornot & \oddornot \\
  \oddornot & \oddornot & \oddornot \\
  \oddornot & \oddornot & \oddornot
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

I'm assuming a solution approach would entail a redefinition of `&` and `\\` for counter stepping and renewal. However, I'm not comfortable doing that without (perhaps) breaking something else along the way.

Comment: Add `\relax` in front of `\ifodd`: TeX tries to expand the first token in a cell looking for `\omit`, so the conditional is evaluated before the counters are stepped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something not unlike this (although to do a full job you'd have to worry more about nested tables (which needs a stack to reset and restore the global counter) and `\multicolumn` (which needs to advance the column counter by the appropriate amount)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\makeatletter
\def\insert@column{%
   \the@toks \the \@tempcnta
   \global\advance\c@tabcol\@ne
   \ignorespaces \@sharp \unskip
   \the@toks \the \count@ \relax}

\let\old@arraycr\@arraycr
\def\@arraycr{\global\c@tabcol\z@\global\advance\c@tabrow\@ne\old@arraycr}

\let\old@tabarray\@tabarray
\def\@tabarray{\global\c@tabrow\@ne\global\c@tabcol\z@\old@tabarray}

\makeatother
\newcounter{tabcol}\newcounter{tabrow}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol)
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` is similar to the classical `{array}` (of the package `array`) but has (among other features) built-in LaTeX counters `iRow` and `jCol` for the rows and the columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{NiceArray}{ccc}
    (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}) & (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}) & (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}) \\
    (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}) & (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}) & (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}) \\
    (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}) & (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}) & (\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol})
  \end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}​
```

[image: Output of the first code]

In fact, `nicematrix` has also a command `\AutoNiceMatrix` to construct a matrix from a pattern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[\AutoNiceMatrix{6-6}{(\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol})}\]
\end{document}​
```

[image: Output of the second code]