# Number of row in a tabular

Tags: tables, counters

Is there a simple way to get the number of rows of a given tabular ?

More precisely, I have a variable `\t@b` which contains something like

```
foo & bar \\ foo & bar \\ foo & bar
```

I will display the content of this variable inside a tabular environment.
The number of columns is determined, but how can I find the number of rows of the resulting tabular ?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I do not think there is a relevant MWE to produce here (I do not have an error to show). I just want to know how to count the number of rows of `\begin{tabular} \t@b \end{tabular}` given `\t@b` (or equivalently the number of occurences of ` \\ ` inside `\t@b`).

Comment: @Arkandias see, Christian had to make a test file as you did not supply one. It _always_ helps people who are answering if you supply a test file.

Comment: essentially a duplicate of this, although you apparently only want the final value, not have the number printed each row: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers?rq=1

Comment: It seems as if you're trying to reinvent some wheel. Not sure if this helps but the `pgfplotstable` and the `datatool` package provide high-level support for database table. Also see this [database-related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48193/reading-data-from-a-relational-database-into-a-latex-table).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a new column type which automatically counts the number of rows, e.g. by using the `array` package and the `\newcolumntype`. I assumed to have a left justified 2nd column.

This does not work, if the `L` column is specified more than once, of course!

```
\documentclass{book}%

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%


\newcounter{numberofrows}%

\pretocmd{\tabular}{\setcounter{numberofrows}{0}}{}{} % Resetting the number of rows counter

\def\tablecontent{%
  foo & bar \\ foo & bar \\ foo & bar \\
}%

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\stepcounter{numberofrows}}l}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{Ll}%
\tablecontent
\tablecontent
\tablecontent
\tablecontent
\tablecontent
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

The last table has \thenumberofrows~rows


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{L*{100}{l}}%
Hello \tabularnewline
World!\tabularnewline
This \tabularnewline
is \tabularnewline
a \tabularnewline
nice  \tabularnewline
table \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

The last table has \thenumberofrows~rows




\end{document}
```

[image]

## New version, counting the number of `\\` in a macro

Using the `xstring` package and its `\StrCount` macro, it's possible to count the `\\` in the `\t@b` macro. (However, it will not check, if there is a trailing `\\` at the end and there should be no intermixing of `\tabularnewline` and `\\` (I did not test this actually).

```
\documentclass{book}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xstring}%

\def\tablecontent{%
  foo & bar \\ foo & bar \\ foo & bar \\ foo & bar \\ foo & bar \\ %
}%

\gdef\newlinecounts{}%


\gdef\newlinemacro{\\}%


\newcommand{\GetNumberOfRows}[2][\newlinecounts]{%
\expandarg%
\StrCount{#2}{\newlinemacro}[#1]%
}%



\begin{document}

\GetNumberOfRows{\tablecontent}
Number of table rows (looking ahead): \newlinecounts 

And now finally the table\par

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}%
\tablecontent
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to mention that if the "data" in the `tabular` environment are entered in a more conventional way than is the case in your MWE, one needs to remember to specify an extra `&` before the `\\` line break directives, so that the count incrementor has a chance to kick in.

Comment: A more easy way to ensure the counting is to use the first column for this ;-)

Comment: You should definitely mention in full what the easiest method may be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a way to get the row number without printing the tabular, or at least _before_ it?

Comment: @Arkandias: That's another question ;-)

Comment: OK sorry for not specifying enough my question. The problem is that I need to treat differently the tabular depending on the number of rows (actually I will add a first row before ``\t@b``, that will depend on the number of rows inside ``\t@b``).

Comment: @Arkandias: Isn't it easier to count the number of `\\` in your `\t@b` macro?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do that either...

Comment: @Arkandias: I added a version that counts the number of `\\` such it's possible to know the number of rows ahead, under special conditions

Comment: could this also be possible in combination with `csvreader`?

Comment: @API: I've never used `csvreader`, so I can't give no answer on your question

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to get the number of rows in a given `tabular`?

Use some of the ideas in [Coounter for use in `array`/`tabular` cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65649/5764). Below I've added `\savetabularrows{<label>}` which stores the number of rows using the traditional `\label`-`\ref` system. This allows you to `\ref{<label>}` it elsewhere in the document, or use `\thetabrow` directly (after the table):

[image]

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65649/5764
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\makeatletter
\def\insert@column{%
   \the@toks \the \@tempcnta
   \global\advance\c@tabcol\@ne
   \ignorespaces \@sharp \unskip
   \the@toks \the \count@ \relax}

\let\old@arraycr\@arraycr
\def\@arraycr{\global\c@tabcol\z@\global\advance\c@tabrow\@ne\old@arraycr}

\let\old@tabarray\@tabarray
\def\@tabarray{\global\c@tabrow\@ne\global\c@tabcol\z@\old@tabarray}

\newcommand{\savetabularrows}[1]{\edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{tabrow}}\label{#1}}

\makeatother
\newcounter{tabcol}\newcounter{tabrow}
\begin{document}

The following \verb|array| has \ref{arrayrows}~rows.

\[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol)
  \end{array}
  \savetabularrows{arrayrows}
\]

The following \verb|tabular| has \ref{tabularrows}~rows.

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) \\
    (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol) & (\thetabrow,\thetabcol)
  \end{tabular}%
  \savetabularrows{tabularrows}%
\end{center}

\end{document}​
```

Comment: Thanks, but in order to determine the number or rows you have to print the tabular first, don't you? I would like to get the number of rows before printing the tabular...

Comment: @Arkandias: I've updated the answer to use the `\label`-`\ref` system. You can now use the row count wherever you wish via `\ref{<label>}`.

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but with further functionalities.

Among these, at the end of the environment, the LaTeX counter `iRow` contains the total number of rows of the tabular.

Actually, it's not exactly a LaTeX counter since it disappears at the end of the environment (by design). So, if you want to use its value outside the environement, you have to store its value in another LaTeX counter by an instruction in the `\CodeAfter` of the `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{NumberOfRows}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
foo & bar \\
foo & bar \\
foo & bar \\
foo & bar \\
foo & bar \\
foo & bar \\
foo & bar \\
foo & bar \\
foo & bar \\
\CodeAfter
  \setcounter{NumberOfRows}{\value{iRow}}
\end{NiceTabular}

The number of rows is \arabic{NumberOfRows}.

\end{document}​
```

[image: Output of the above code]