# tabular environment: incrementing the headings

Tags: tables, loops

Is it possible to let LaTeX increment the headings in a `table` environment?  If so, how could I do this?

For example, I would like to have 7 columns and 7 rows where the columns except the first are `blue = $1$ & blue = $2$ & ...` and similarly the rows except the first are `red = $1$ & ....`

Is there a way to have LaTeX do this?  In `TikZ`, I could use a `foreach` loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    & blue = $1$ & blue = $2$ & blue = $3$ & ... \\
    red = $1$ & & ... \\
    red = $2$ & & ... \\
    red = $3$ & & ... \\
    ...
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you fill in more of the `...` to show the desired table. I have a suspicion (given the comments on my answer) that I can't guess what you intend.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle already edited to show intent better.

Comment: It's still very unclear (I'd _never_ have guessed you meant the layout Werner showed:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's that crystal ball I carry around... ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what book would you recommend to read to grasp this part of LaTeX better?

Comment: @dustin not sure what "this part" is, the latex companion is the canonical book for most things, but the package documentation or this site are free;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way, all supported by [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) for insertion of content at the start of a cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{bluecol}\newcounter{redrow}
\newcommand{\insertblue}{%
  \relax\ifnum\value{bluecol}>0 blue${}=\number\numexpr7-\value{bluecol}$\addtocounter{bluecol}{-1}\fi}
\newcommand{\insertred}{%
  \stepcounter{redrow}red${}= \theredrow$}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{redrow}{0}
\setcounter{bluecol}{6}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\insertred}c*{6}{|>{\insertblue}c}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &&&&&& \\
  &&&&&& \\
  &&&&&& \\
  &&&&&& \\
  &&&&&& \\
  &&&&&& \\
  &&&&&& \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The first `\multicolumn` is to prevent `red` from being set in the first row.

Comment: Oh well OK if that's what he meant you get +1 and a crystal ball and I'll delete my answer:-)

Comment: as promised :-)

Comment: I have a follow question on automating the entries since they will go something like `(1, 1) & (0, 2) & (0, 3) & ... & (0, 6)` for row 2 as an example.  This entries are built on a rule though.  I cant seem to determine how to execute it from what I learned from this post though.  Should I include it here or make a new question?

Comment: Could you describe the rule? I assume this doesn't only hold for row 2, but for other rows as well. You may be interested in looking at [Counters for use in `array`/`tabular` cells](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65649/5764).

Comment: The rule is the larger number is chosen from red or blue.  Then X is 0 for blue chosen and 1 for red.  Y is the number chosen.

Comment: I forgot to mention the tie goes to red.