# How can you automatically number the entries in an (m x n)-array?

Tags: lists, enumerate, arrays

If one uses
\begin{enumerate}
\item Entry1
\item Entry2
:
\end{enumerate}
Latex generates a vertical numbered list of the form

1. Entry1
2. Entry2

But how can one get automated numbering when one wants the thing to be generated look like this:

1. Entry1    2. Entry2    3. Entry3
2. Entry4    5. Entry5    6. Entry6
3. Entry7    8. Entry8    9. Entry9     ...?

Comment: Maybe the items/entries should be (1,1), (1,2),... (1,n) \\ ...\\ (m,1), (m,2), ... (m,n) ?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65649/counters-for-use-in-array-tabular-cells

Comment: The numbering scheme seems odd, not being able to make up its mind whether to number by cell or by row.  What is the actual formula for defining the cell numbers?

Comment: As it happens, my Entries are going to be little math arrays representing arguments--an underlined sentence (the premise) above another sentence (the conclusion). I want to arrange 90 of these, in 14 rows and 5 columns, while numbering them

Comment: My Entries are going to be little math arrays--an underlined sentence (the premise) above another sentence (the conclusion). I want to arrange 90 of these, in 14 rows and 5 columns, while numbering them 1,2,3,4,5 (first row); 6,7,8,9,10 (second row); etc.  It's the numbering that I would like to handle automatically, working with the entries (the little arrays) as the items being enumerated.  I have a suboptimal solution of using tabbing with six columns---the first five for the arrays/entries, and the sixth column for a quintuple of numbers (like [1,2,3,4,5] for the first row).

Comment: Thanks John Kormylo for that link. I played around with the commands a bit, and have managed now to get the numbers going up automatically in each row. But I've had to resort to the kludge of re-using the setcounter command to get the numbers increased by 5 when dealing with a new row in an array with 5 columns.